# Does AWS cloudfront support TLSv1.3 for custom origin?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

Does cloudfront support TLSv1.3 I dont see any docs that says that it supports between cloudfront and custom origin? I have a very strong requirement to use TLSv1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFront doesn't support TLS1.3. (Viewer to CloudFront and CloudFront to Origin both).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/secure-connections-supported-viewer-protocols-ciphers.html

Comment: This answer is outdated. See the answer below from @Christian , it is accepted since early September 2020

Comment: Yes, this is outdated, feature was introduced later and cristian added the answer , thanks cristian

Answer (score 9):

CloudFront now supports TLS 1.3—it's enabled by default.

Here are the docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/secure-connections-supported-viewer-protocols-ciphers.html